# Getting error regarding "os" module of python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-os

I am using python2.7 on ubuntu system. I am getting following errors while working with "os":

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fsencode'

On this line:

```
 directory=os.fsencode(indir)
```

I have checked other solutions but they are not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2.7 has no `os.fsencode()` function, that's a [*Python 3 only* function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fsencode). It was [introduced in Python 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#os) and not backported.

If you need a backport, you'll have to first backport the [`sys.getfilesystemencoding()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding), which is platform dependent, and you'd have to take into account changes to how different Python versions have handled filename encoding (for Windows, Python 3.6 and up changed to UTF-8, older versions use the `mbcs` codec, which is locale dependent).

Comment: Okay. I didn't know that. Previously I had python3.6 so it was working fine. Thank you. @Martijn Pieters.